# Spring Data MongoDB Authentication Error

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I cannot insert a document object with spring-data-mongodb. I have configured MongoDB in my spring-mvc project like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { "com.example.store.repository" })
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws UnknownHostException {
        ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017);
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential("username", "store", "password".toCharArray());
        MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder().connectionsPerHost(4).socketKeepAlive(true).build();
        Mongo mongo = new MongoClient(serverAddress, Arrays.asList(credential), options);
        return mongo;
    }

    @Bean(name = "MongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), "store");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "store";
    }

}
```

I have added repository and the document as well. In one of my controller I insert a dummy document like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String addProduct() {
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName("New Product");
    product.setDescription("Product Description");
    product.setUnitPrice(19.99);

    productRepository.insert(product);

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

When I enter the url corresponding this method, it takes a few seconds and gives this error:

```
 Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'auth failed' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "auth failed", "code" : 18 }}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'auth failed' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "auth failed", "code" : 18 }}}]
```

I cannot reveal the problem. I have a user configured above and I am able to do write and read queries in mongo shell as that user. However, it fails through spring. Why?

Comment: the config above creates more than one bean of type `MongoTemplate` in your context. The one declared as `@Bean(name = "MongoTemplate")` will not be used within the repositories. Though this should not cause the error you encounter... So please try removing that manually declared bean, unless it is used with a `@Qualifier` somewhere in your code, and give it a try then. Have you got a small sample reproducing the error you can point me to? Which MongoDB server, mongo-java-client and Spring-Data-MongoDB versions are you using?

Comment: @ChristophStrobl actually sir, I do not know what is going on clearly. I try to make it work by using this article: http://viveksoni.net/setting-up-spring-data-mongodb-spring-mvc-project-in-intellij/. I have mongodb3 running in the same machine. mongo-java-driver: 3.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this code as MongoConfiguration it might help you and let me know if it has solved your problem

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { "com.example.store.repository" })
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Mongo mongo() throws UnknownHostException {
    return mongoClient();
  }

  @Bean
  public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
  }

  @Bean
  public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), null);
  }

  @Override
  protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return "store";
  }

  @Bean
  public MongoClient mongoClient() {    
    List<MongoCredential> credentialsList = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
    credentialsList.add(MongoCredential.createCredential("username", getDatabaseName(), "password".toCharArray());
    ServerAddress primary = new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017);
    MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder().connectionsPerHost(4).socketKeepAlive(true).build();
    return new MongoClient(Arrays.aslist(primary), credentialsList, mongoClientOptions); 
  }

}
```